# Setting up MySQL replication?

Tags: mysql, database, replication

UPDATE: have edited to add actual data to the database, but still the same problem.

I'm working with a vanilla install of Debian (6.0.1), up-to-date versions of MySQL, and trying to set up MySQL database replication.

This is what I've done so far:

```
$ apt-get upgrade
$ apt-get install mysql-client mysql-server 
$ vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf
  # Comment out bind-addressb 
  # bind-address            = 127.0.0.1 
  # Add these lines
  log-bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
  binlog-do-db=exampledb
  server-id=1
$ /etc/init.d/mysql restart
$ mysql -u root -p
> CREATE DATABASE exampledb;
> USE exampledb;
> CREATE TABLE berries (name VARCHAR(100));
> INSERT INTO berries VALUES ('cherry');
> INSERT INTO berries VALUES ('bilberry');
> exit;
$ /etc/init.d/mysql restart
$ mysql -u root -p
> GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'slave_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '<some_password>'; 
> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
> USE exampledb;
> INSERT INTO berries VALUES ('blackberry');
> FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;
> SHOW MASTER STATUS;
```

At this point, apparently I should see some details of the log file, but what I'm seeing instead is:

```
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Any ideas? `/var/log/mysql.err` and `/var/log/mysql.log` are both empty, even after another restart.

Thanks!

Comment: Dont you need to do something on this database before it'll show a status? There won't be anything in the binary log until an operation takes place if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Did you try restarting MySQL again after creating the database? You should also try creating a table and inserting some test values in there before attempting to view the status. If you're following the howtoforge tutorial, take note of this: `Both systems have MySQL installed, and the database exampledb with tables and data is already existing on the master, but not on the slave.`

Comment: Thanks. I've tried doing that - and edited the question accordingly - but I'm still seeing 'empty set', and log files still empty :(

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out in the end.

The clue is in the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto-masterstatus.html), where it says:

```
In a different session on the master, use the SHOW MASTER STATUS statement
```

I was using the same session :)